# When can we recover a manifold when we attach a $2n$-cell to $S^n$?

Tags: algebraic-topology, manifolds

I have a question related to [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/21304/manifold-with-3-nondegenerate-critical-points/21346#21346).  In my answer I was going to try and say something about the possible manifolds that might arise in this way, i.e. as mapping cones of elements of $\pi_{2n-1}(S^n)$.  Certainly not all of them will be manifolds.  At first I felt like there should be a reason why we'd need to be using a torsion-free homotopy generator if we want a manifold (in which case we could appeal to Serre's theorem that the only non-torsion part of the homotopy groups of spheres is $\pi_n(S^n)=\mathbb{Z}$ and $\pi_{4n-1}(S^{2n})=\mathbb{Z}$), but then I realized I couldn't think of any reason why that should be true.  Also I was hoping the Hopf invariant would enter into the picture too, since that's a pretty obvious tool at our disposal, but I couldn't get anywhere with that either...and I think at this point I'm more or less all out of tricks.  Does anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe this is related to the Hopf invariant one problem.  Let $X = S^n \cup_f B^{2n}$.

The attaching map from $B^{2n}$ is a map $f$ from $S^{2n-1}$ to $S^n$.  I think one way of thinking about the Hopf invariant of this map is as follows.

Let $x\in H^n(X)$.  Then $x^2 = k y$ where $y$ generates $H^{2n}(X)$.  The number $k$ is the Hopf invariant.

In order for $X$ to be a manifold, it must satisfy Poincare duality (so long as $n>1$ - if $n=1$ different stuff can happen), which implies that $k = \pm 1$.  But Adams has shown you can only have Hopf invariant 1 when $n = 2, 4, 8$, getting you something homotopy equivalent to $\mathbb{C}P^2$, $\mathbb{H} P^2$ or $\mathbb{O}P^2$.

**Edit**:  As pointed out by Denis Gorodkov, (communicated by G. Sassatelli), this last sentence is false.  In the case of $\mathbb{C}P^n$, it is true as any manifold with the cohomology ring of $\mathbb{C}P^n$ is homotopy equivalent to it.  But the cohomology rings of $\mathbb{H}P^2$ and $\mathbb{O}P^2$ do not determine the homotopy type - see the comments.

**End edit**

The $n=1$ case, you're attaching a disc to a circle and getting a manifold.  Here, since $\pi_1(X)$ may be nontrivial, one cannot neccesarily use Poincare duality.  However, by a simple analysis, the only manifold this can give rise to is $\mathbb{R}P^2$.

*Edit*  If one wants to avoid cases ($n = 1$ vs $n > 1$) then one can work with cohomology with $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$ coefficients instead.

Comment: Thanks for fixing my typo.  I was thinking $16$ because for some reason I have $\mathbb{O}P^2$ on the brain.

Comment: This is probably obvious, but why do we need $x^2=y$?  The dual statement is that a representative of $H_n$ needs to have self-intersection number 1, and I don't see any reason that that needs to hold either.

Comment: It's Poincare duality.  There must be SOME element in $z\in H^n(X)$ such that $xz = y$.  Since $x$ generates all of $H^n(X)$, $z = a x$ for some nonzero integer $a$.  But then $xz = xax = ax^2 = y$ implies $y$ is a multiple of $x^2$.  But $y$ is a generator, so this implies $a = \pm 1$.  So, up to rechoosing $-y$ instead of $y$, we must have $x^2 = y$.

Comment: But why must there exist such a  $z$?  Sorry if I'm being really dense here.

Comment: It's corollary 3.39 in Hatcher's algebraic topology.  The idea is that if $[M]$ is the fundamental class and $x$ is not a multiple of anything, nor is torsion, then $[M]\cap x$ is also not a multiple of anything, nor is torsion.  It follows that there is a cocycle $z$ such that $z([M]\cap x) = 1$.  But by the formula connecting cap and cup product, we get that $1 = z([M]\cap x) = z \cup x ([M])$, so the $z$ above exists.

Comment: Ohhhhh okay.  Very cool.  I didn't read Hatcher carefully enough, clearly...  Thanks for the answer and explanation!

Comment: User Denis Gorodkov wanted to make this comment, which I report: "The homotopy equivalence is not true for $\Bbb HP^2$ and $\Bbb OP^2$. More precisely, there are 6 homotopy classes for manifolds admitting a Morse function with 3 critical points in dimension $8$, and 60 homotopy classes in dimension $16$. The problem is that Adams's work gives you only the isomorphism of cohomology rings, but not homotopy equivalence. **[to be continued...]**"

Comment: **[... continues]** "See [this](http://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/BF02684323) article for a precise enumeration of explicit examples and a complete description of all (smooth, topological, combinatorial) manifolds that allow a Morse function with 3 critical points."

Comment: Thanks for the correction!  I don't know what I was thinking when I originally wrote that.